# Spring MVC in a multi maven module project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I am designing and implementing a Java web application using Spring, Spring MVC and Maven. My goal is to create three modules:

- a data module containing entities and DAOs
- a service module containing the business logic and the @Service classes
- a web module containing jsp files and the @Controller classes

Communications between the service module and the data module work great. The service module depends on the data module and it includes the data module with `<import resource="dataApplicationContext.xml"/>` in serviceApplicatioContext.xml. I have tested it with a static main class and some integration tests.

The problem I am having is about making the web module to depend on the service module. How do I make my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml import my serviceApplicatioContext.xml?

Solution I have tried so far:
1)If I just use `<import resource="/serviceApplicationContext.xml"/>` then Spring MVC would look for /WEB-INF/serviceApplicationContext.xml which, of course, does not exist.

2)If I replace `<context:component-scan base-package="my.project.controller" />` with `<context:component-scan base-package="my.project" />` then Spring does not kick in and no hibernate session is created.

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Comment: Assuming the configuration is in the classpath (i.e. inside your jar file) use the `classpath:` prefix. I.e. `<import resource="classpath:serviceApplicationContext.xml" />`. I would also suggest you do this inside your service context for the data context file. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#resources-app-ctx for more info on resource loading inside an application context.

Comment: Thanks Deinum. I am making progress. I need to sort out the right place for jdbc.properties and then, fingers crossed, I should be OK. Thanks again

Comment: Deinum, if you write your comment as an answer I am happy to mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring has its own [resource loading](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#resources-app-ctx) mechanism and each implementation of an `ApplicationContext` has its own default resource location. The `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` by defaults loads from the classpath, whereas the `XmlWebApplicationContext` loads from the web application root.

You can specify on each resource where to load it from by prefixing it. `classpath:` leads to always loading from the classpath, `file:` from the file-system etc.

In short simply add `classpath:` to the name of the resources to import to force that this file is always loaded from the classpath.

```
<import resource="classpath:serviceApplicationContext.xml" />
```